# Area Under A Circle $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1^2$

Tags: integration

How do I calculate the area under a circle that is centered on $(0,1)$? I would like to use the formula for a circle, but I'm not sure it can be done. 
I get the equation : $$y^2 -2y = -x^2$$

Comment: Do you mean the area bounded between the circle, x-axis and the vertical lines $x = \pm 1$?

Comment: The area (enclosed by the circle) is certainly $\pi$, but what should you use? Integrals? Double integrals? Something else?

Comment: Hi. Ahmad. Thanks for the rapid reply. I mean the area between the circle, the x-axis and the vertical line x = 1. Thanks.

Comment: @Frederick  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

We have that

$$x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1^2$$

is centered at $(0,1)$ with radius $1$ therefore the area under the circle and the $x$ axis can be evaluated from the area of a square/rectangle and the area of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

From the following equation, we have the graph,

[image]

$$x = \sqrt{2y-y^2}$$
By integrating for first-half(right side) we have bounds as $y=0$ and $y=2$, 
$$\int^{2}_{0}\sqrt{2y-y^{2}}dy = \left(\dfrac{y\sqrt{2y-y^2}}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}{2}-\dfrac{\arcsin\left(\frac{2-2y}{2}\right)}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
From the symmetry we can double the area to find total area,
$$Area = 2*\frac{\pi}{2} = \pi$$